# how to create this kind of plot and fill it with different color in R or python?

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, ggplot2

[image]

This is structure of plant root, I want to generate this plot, then the different part will be assigned different color to represent the expression level of different genes. Since there will be many genes, I want to use R or python to plot it. Can anyone suggest a tool for this?

Comment: *Can anyone suggest a tool for this?* - gimp or photoshop? I don't see how one could achieve this with standard `ggplot2` or pythons `matplotlib` without going insane

Answer (score 1):

You could code the contours of this figure as a map (a set of paths), then assign each countour a number according to region. Then it becomes easy to color by region any way you want it. ggplot2 can draw maps and you can find many examples of this usage. But you must digitize the figure and vectorize it first. That's all I can say.

Comment: That sounds actually like a doable (but still labor intensive) approach! Good suggestion.

Comment: Maybe the spatial package such as R "sf" can do this? But I need to find how to make a map